# Gradle - create catalog can not import the dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm using gradle 7-4-1 and I'm trying to use a catalog to share dependencies between subprojects as documentation

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sec:sharing-catalogs

This is my settings.gradle.kts

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            version("log4j", "2.17.1")
            library("log4j-api", "org.apache.logging.log4j", "log4j-api").versionRef("log4j")
            library("log4j-core", "org.apache.logging.log4j", "log4j-core").versionRef("log4j")
            library("log4j-slf4j-impl", "org.apache.logging.log4j", "log4j-slf4j-impl").versionRef("log4j")
            bundle("log4j", listOf("log4j-api", "log4j-core", "log4j-slf4j-impl"))
        }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "gawds-db"
include("db-server", "db-client", "db-common")
enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")
```

And I'm trying to import into my build.gradle.kts (located in my subproject)

```
plugins {
    `maven-publish`
    application
    `java-library`
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configure<JavaApplication> {
    mainClass.set("com.gawds.db.MainApp")
}

tasks.compileJava {
    options.isIncremental = true
    options.isFork = true
    options.isFailOnError = false
}

tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.log4j.api)
    implementation(libs.log4j.core)
    implementation(libs.log4j.log4j.slf4j.impl)
}
```

**Note**: also tried

```
    implementation(libs.bundles.log4j)
```

But neither referencing libs.alias nor libs.bundles.alias-bundle work.

My project structure is:

```
 /
 | settings.gradle.kts
 | db-server /
      | build.gradle.kts
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case helps someone else. First, not sure why intellij marks as red, however from cmd line looks like it works.

From **settings.gradle.kts** get rid of

```
enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")
```

This was required in previous versions but not in gradle **7.4.x**

Also u need to add the repos in the catalog section, see below:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            version("log4jVersion", "2.17.1")
            library("log4j-api", "org.apache.logging.log4j", "log4j-api").versionRef("log4jVersion")
            library("log4j-core", "org.apache.logging.log4j", "log4j-core").versionRef("log4jVersion")
            library("log4j-slf4j-impl", "org.apache.logging.log4j", "log4j-slf4j-impl").versionRef("log4jVersion")
            bundle("log4j", listOf("log4j-api", "log4j-core", "log4j-slf4j-impl"))
        }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "gawds-db"
include("db-server", "db-client", "db-common")
```

Another important point that I did wrong in my tests are:

Assuming this alias:

```
log4j-slf4j-impl
```

the typesafe equivalent is

```
log4j.slf4j.impl
```

so we need to call in the build.gradle.kts:

```
implementation(libs.log4j.slf4j.impl)
```

Also u can print the alias to check the name using:

```
val versionCatalog = extensions.getByType<VersionCatalogsExtension>().named("libs")
println("${versionCatalog.libraryAliases}")
```

To improve the previous code, we can create a task to print the catalog alias:

```
abstract class PrintCatalogAlias @Inject constructor(private val r : Project) :  DefaultTask() {
    @org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction
    fun catalogAlias() {
        val versionCatalog = r.rootProject.project.extensions.getByType<VersionCatalogsExtension>().named("libs")
        println("${versionCatalog.libraryAliases}")
    }
}

tasks.register<PrintCatalogAlias>("catalog")
```